# assign the date value reading from file in shell script and update the file

Tags: shell, date, variables

I have to assign the date value to a variable by reading from a file and minus it by 15 minutes and update the file again with current date. For some reason my shell is not working and every time my Date_Start is coming as now - 15 minutes instead of time in file - 15 minutes.

```
start = `cat test.txt`

    Date_Start=`date -u --date="$start - 15 minutes" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`
    Date_End=`date -u +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`

    destdir=/c/test.txt

    if [ -f "$destdir" ]
    then
        echo "$Date_End" > "$destdir"

    fi
```

Comment: What is in `test.txt`?

Comment: also there should be no gap in = sign when you are assigning start